# Which resources method should handle this view?

Tags: laravel

I'm currently using Laravel but i assume this question could also be asked with any framework in any language.

If i have a simple form to create an user, with the most basic fields (firstname, lastname, email...), the resource method i'll use will be `create` to display the view and `store` to handle the post logic.

After that, the edit form will be displayed in the `edit` method and the update managed by the `update` method.

Eventually, the user sheet will use the `show` method.

Now, imagine i have a view that combine both the `edit` and `show` purposes, i mean like a page with multiple tabs, where each tab display information about the user, some charts, some tables, a lot of stuff... but also an edit form in one of these tabs.

Which method should be used to display this view ? `edit` or `show` ? Since it acts like a `show` but also have a form to `edit` the user... i'm always asking myself and sometimes i have a hard time to figure out which method i should use.

This case often happens in back offices, where some edit pages looks like a dashboard more than a simple form, i'm sure you see what i mean ;)

Is there a convention about this ? Something like "if there is a form it's an edit, even if it mainly show information" ?

Comment: You may send a response to view from your controller about usage of this view. Something like `return view("user.index",["usage"=>"show"]) ` And in your view, you can make an if else clause about this usage